# Atlassian Pipelines and Angular CLI

Tags: angular-cli, bitbucket-pipelines

Trying to set up pipelines with Angular CLI and running into an issue when calling `ng build`.

```
pipelines:
   default:
     - step:
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - npm --version
          - npm install
          - ng build
```

angular-cli is a dev dependency in my package.json, but ng cannot be found.

```
bash: ng: command not found
```

What step did I miss or doing wrong? 
Thank-you

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it had to be called from npm context. I ended up calling npm build and added the script for it in the package.json

```
"build": "ng build"
```

Answer (score 4):

After including `npm build` as suggested above, things seemed to run successfully but it did actually not do anything. I had to replace it with `$(npm bin)/ng build` in order to work.

Comment: you need to do "npm run build"

Answer (score 4):

It worked for me.

```
image: node:10

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - npm install
          - npm install -g @angular/cli
          - ng build --prod
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call in the npm context Just like suggested above. In your package.json write a script:

```
"scripts": {
        "build": "ng build"
}
```

then you can have

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - npm --version
          - npm install
          - npm build
```

which will run `ng build`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this too:

```
  pipelines:
   default:
     - step:
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - npm --version
          - npm install
          - npm run ng build
```

Answer (score -1):

Angular CLI is not installed in your docker image.

Use this configuration:

```
image: trion/ng-cli # Any docker image from dokerhub with angular cli installed.

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - node
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - npm install
          - npm run build
```